# flatmap a list of keys and sets into a list of pairs

Tags: kotlin

I'm doing an online course and misread a question (which is why I think it's okay to post this question as the answer isn't anything to do with what was asked on the course!).

```
data class Trip(
        val driver: Driver,
        val passengers: Set<Passenger>,
        ...
)

val trips: List<Trip>
```

so it would end up something like

```
[
    driver1 : passenger1
    driver1 : passenger2
    driver2 : passenger1
    driver2 : passenger3
...
]
```

What I want to do is to create a list of all instances of driver and passenger, probably as pairs and I just can't think how to do it.

```
trips.map {t -> Pair (t.driver, t.passengers)}
```

gets me some what there but obviously leaves me with the set of passengers rather than the driver:passenger pairs unpacked.  II can't get the syntax for a flatmap so

```
 trips.flatMap {t -> Pair (t.driver, t.passengers)}
```

complains that the Pair isn't iterable which I understand but I can't grasp how I would unpack the set and maintain the individual link to the driver ?

(the actual question I noticed when composing this question gives you an individual driver to find the passengers for which makes it quite a bit easier and I've done this...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for every trip you want every combination of driver/passenger, and then you want a list of all these?  If so, would this do?

```
trips.flatMap { trip -> 
    trip.passengers.map { passenger -> 
        Pair(trip.driver, passenger) 
    } 
}
```

That gives you a `List<Pair<Driver, Passenger>>`, if that's what you're looking for?  It will potentially contain duplicates, so you might want to handle that in some way.

Comment: it's going to take me some time to get my head around that (I was going more down the map->flatmap route, which I guess means I haven't quite grasped the real point of lambda's yet...  Yes, I realise about the dupes, I thought I was looking for all passengers who'd used any driver more than once so was going process this list further but then realised I was only looking for repeat passengers for a specific driver...

Comment: Yeah, functional programming takes a while to get your head around.  If you don't have any luck put a comment in here asking for more info and I'll update my answer with a more verbose explanation.  Good luck.